Futuristic movie - man being tortured, another writing in sand
I really need help identifying a movie. It has plagued me for pretty much all my life because at the very beginning of my life is when I saw it. It had to have been made anywhere from 1980-1990, give or take, more early than later in that general time, possibly late 70s. I can describe to you some of the scenes in this movie. I know nothing about it! Like the actors or a name or anything. The language was in English so I assume it is an American/Hollywood movie. 
Not sure if it was a TV movie or if it came to video or what but I imagine as a kid watching endless hours of TV it came out on TV or aired on TV and such. Now to some scenes in the movie. Oh yeah, for that time period, this was a pretty futuristic-esque type movie for, again, that time period. Not futuristic like we would think today, in that sense, but for that time period. It seemed like in this movie there were other worlds conversing and such, maybe coming together for some big event or something. (Think the series "V" but not alien invasion type) 
Well one of the scenes the evildoers had a man naked or at least in underwear on a table in a room tied down and there was an illusion (to best describe) of ants or bugs covering his entire body (they were not doing anything like biting or eating him, I don't think) but to the victim it was very real and a torture type scare tactic. but I remember the scene vividly that the person in control of the "torture" turned it on and off like a light switch. That is one scene I recall. 
Another scene, there is a character that is a male that I do not think can talk, he has a big bird with him, I think, on his shoulder or in his hand like a bird guy, could have been an eagle, not sure, do not remember the bird, he has long black hair and at one scene he draws something in the sand with his finger to illustrate something to some people and I remember some "mean" type character, bullyish if you will, messes up the sand of what he was drawing with his finger as if to say you are stupid. This character that drew in the sand, may have had some feather type thing in his hair. 
I thought this movie was called The Last Starfighter, as the name seems like it would have been fitting but that was definitely not the movie as I watched that as a means of elimination. I know two vague scenes from a movie is hard to figure out but I hope someone out there can cure this plague for me. Another thing, this movie would definitely be Science Fiction or Fantasy.

Any chance at all you could rewrite that out of a wall-of-text and into more readable formatting?

Solarbabies (AKA Solarwarriors or Solarfighters) from 1986:

In a future in which most water has disappeared from the Earth, we find a group of children, mostly teenagers, who are living at an orphanage, run by the despotic rulers of the new Earth. The group in question plays a hockey based game on roller skates and is quite good. It has given them a unity that transcends the attempts to bring them to heel by the government. Finding an orb of special power, they find it has unusual effects on them.

It has a scene where someone is strapped to a table in his underwear and tortured with an ant hologram and a character called Darstar who can talk to birds and has an owl sidekick. And in another scene:

(Darstar has drawn a picture in the sand. A crowd gathers around to see what he's up to. He kneels by the picture and closes his eyes. Soon two crows fly down. One lands on the picture, the other lands on Dark Star's shoulder. Everyone is impressed, but before anything else can happen Gavial and his lame friends walk up and destroy the picture.) 

Here's the trailer:




I want to watch this just for the name.
